# jQuery ajax data.success returns false

Tags: jquery, ajax

Even though my process.php works, `data.success` returns false. I've been trying to debug it, but I couldn't find the error causing this.

It shows "OKAY!" message only if I change `data.success` to `!data.success`, why?

**html**

```
<form id="my" action="" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">

    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>">
    <input id="save" type="submit" name="changeit" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#my').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var formData = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/modules/settings/process.php', // the url where we want to POST
                data: formData // our data object
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#my').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + "OKAY!." + '</div>');
                }
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: pass datatype in ajax function

Comment: How are you returning the value from server?

Comment: Seems your issue is server side. Your AJAX request is not the issue here.

Comment: So you meant `data.success` should return `true`. So why not asking question regarding server side code?

Comment: console.log(data) , in done callback and check the value

Comment: Thanks for the warnings, I am debugging now.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove `action=""` from your `form` header, less is more
2. try this code for the `ajax` part

   ```
   $.ajax({url: '/modules/settings/process.php', type: 'post', data: $('form').serialize(), success: function(data){
          $('#my').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + "OKAY!." + '</div>');
       }
   });
   ```